# Factory already registered: user (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Description of problem:**
- I've setup factory_girl_rails however whenever I try and load a factory it's trying to load it multiple times.

```
Environment:
- rails (3.2.1)
- factory_girl (2.5.2)
- factory_girl_rails (1.6.0)
- ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]

> rake spec --trace
** Execute environment
-- Creating User Factory
-- Creating User Factory
rake aborted!
Factory already registered: user
```

The only other thing I've changed is:
/config/initializers/generator.rb

```
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework = :rspec
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl
end
```

**GEMFILE**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem "rspec-rails"
end

group :test do
  gem "rspec"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

gem 'refinerycms-core',       :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-dashboard',  :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-images',     :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-pages',      :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-resources',  :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-settings',   :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'refinerycms-testing',  :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
end

gem 'refinerycms-inventories', :path => 'vendor/engines'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :role do
    title "MyString"
  end
end
```

This seems to be a compatibility/environment issue that I can't seem to figure out.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: here's my spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
#require 'factory_girl_rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
### Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  #config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicating factories? Incorrect copypaste, or factories defined both in spec/factories.rb and spec/factories/*.rb?

Comment: It will help if you post your user factory file. Also your gemfile and your spec_helper.rb.

Comment: I'm sure that i'm not duplicating factories. Example:  In spec/factories/users.rb I changed factory :user do to factory :user_random_factory_name do and it replied Factory already registered: user_random_factory_name.

Comment: @user1212241: if you have more information/code to add, please edit your question and add it in, as I've now done for you.  Please don't edit someone else's answer to do this.

Comment: Do you happen to be running your tests inside of RubyMine? I had a problem that my file name mask was not set correctly, which made it also pass my factories.rb file to the rspec command, creating this error.

Comment: I found that I was duplicating across `spec/factories/*.rb` and `test/factories/*.rb`. That's one place to check.

Answer (score 39):

The gem `factory_girl_rails` should be required in the `spec_helper.rb` rather than the gemfile - it is possible that you are requiring FactoryGirl twice which is why you are getting the duplicate.

Try this in your gem file:

```
group :test do
  gem "rspec"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
end
```

Then make sure that factory girl is required in the spec_helper with:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

By the way - you don't need both `rspec` and `rpsec-rails` in your gemfile. You can replace both with the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

You need rspec in both groups so that the rake tasks will work in development and the core testing will work in test.

Comment: No luck.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried removing require 'factory_girl_rails' from the spec_helper and still receiving the same error message with gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false

Comment: Couple of things. Can you post your spec_helper.rb? Also, my `config.generators` has the following `g.fixture_replacement   :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'` which you might want to try. Also you don't need `g.test_framework = :rspec` as rspec registers itself with Rails when it is installed so you don't need to explicitly call it.

Comment: I've updated my original post with my spec_helper.rb. I greatly appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: As long as you are doing what I have said above then your gem and spec_helper files seem ok. Can you post your factory file. Perhaps you should try removing the generators as well - these can be done without until this issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you post your factory file.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem recently. In my case one of the files in /factories had a _spec.rb ending (result of creative cp use). It was loading twice, first by rspec and then as a factory.

Comment: I had this problem too. It took me ages before coming across this answer to find that it was causing the problem.

Comment: yep. it was my fail too

Comment: in my case I was running rspec with a single file, but using the factory file path (rspec/factories/myfile.rb) instead of the modelfile path (spec/models/myfile_spec.rb)

Comment: Hahaha same here, almost two hours poking around changing code but still the same and I finally googled the exact error from console and I got to this answer! ‍♂️

Answer (score 16):

Is there any chance you pasted this *whole* snippet for the support file from the config docs?

```
# RSpec
# spec/support/factory_girl.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

# RSpec without Rails
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  end
end
```

If you read the comments you'll see you only want one block or the other. I made this mistake and got the error stated in the question.

Comment: Yep. And that's not the first time I've done that either. Shame.

Comment: Yep I did it too. #oneofusoneofusoneofus

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah those docs need to be fixed, too easy to just drop that in.  Creating a PR for this.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem too. In my case there were two files with the same code, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  end
end
```

One file was named "Useres.rb" and the other "User.rb" so I just deleted "Useres.rb" and fixed the error.

Answer (score 12):

Call `FactoryGirl.define(:user)` or `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` twice you also have this problem.

*Try removing the second call* or:

```
FactoryGirl.factories.clear
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Answer (score 9):

Another possible reason is spare call of `FactoryGirl.find_definitions`.
Try to remove find_definitions if found.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: I had this in /support/factory_girl.rb `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rspec
and there is a comment that says - rspec without rails, copy paste fault :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your individual factory files are not ending with `_spec`.

Comment: I have a "standard_spec" model. I renamed the factory file to standard_spec_factory.rb and everything is working. Obvious, but I wasn't getting it. Thanks, @scarver2.

Comment: The `*_type.rb` suffix is a convention the Ruby community has adopted. Whenever the RSpec test suite runs, it tests all files ending in `_spec.rb`. The obscure issue was that he had a factory file ending with the name `_spec.rb` which RSpec attempted to process as a spec file. By convention, naming all factories with the suffix `_factory.rb` denotes this file is a factory file, not a spec file, thus being ignored by the RSpec processor.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/638

---

Loading factory girl into a development console will do this too:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'; reload!; FactoryGirl.factories.clear; FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

will raise a `FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError` on a sequence under Factory Girl v4.4.0.

It seems the sequences get handled differently within FG and simply wrapping all sequences in a rescue block will solve the issue.

For example:

```
  begin
    sequence :a_sequence do |n|
      n
    end
    sequence :another_sequence do |n|
      n*2
    end
  rescue FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError => e
    warn "#{e.message}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same the problem. What I do is move the spec/factories.rb to spec/factories/role.rb

Comment: Didn't work for me.  My factories are still loading twice. @chamnap. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, I'm using rails 3.2.2.rc1 and factory_girl_rails 1.6.0. Maybe you could try to downgrade the factory_girl_rails.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed spec/factories as spec/setup_data and the problem gone.
Try renaming the spec/factories to anything that suites you, should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem- make sure you aren't loading FactoryGirl a second time in your spec/support/env.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. This happens becouse of you using gem 'refinerycms-testing'? wich requires factory-girl, so you should commit this gem, or commit gem 'factory_girl_rails', don't use all of this gems.

```
    #gem 'refinerycms-testing', '~> 2.0.9', :group => :test
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', :group => :test
```

or

```
    #gem 'factory_girl_rails', :group => :test
    gem 'refinerycms-testing', '~> 2.0.9', :group => :test
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following these steps

1) I looked for all occurrences of "factory_girl" from my RAILS_ROOT:

find . -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "factory_girl"

2) Because this was a full engine plugin "app" that I created via "rails plugin new  --mountable", I had a file under RAILS_ROOT//lib/ called "engine.rb".  It had:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework      :rspec,        :fixture => false
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
  g.assets false
  g.helper false
end
```

3) I also had the following in my spec_helper.rb file:

Dir["#{File.dirname(**FILE**)}/factories/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

4) the g.fixture_replacement line in engine.rb and the Dir line in spec_helper.rb were initializing the factories twice.  I commented out the one from spec_helper.rb and that **fixed the problem**.

Alternatively, you can leave in spec_helper.rb and comment out in engine.rb.

Both fixed the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran with the same issue and commenting out a single line in spec_helper.rb file solved my problem.

Try commenting out this line from spec_helper.rb file and you should be good.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Comment: This line removes support files from `spec_helper.rb`, it's the equivalent of using an atomic bomb to kill a mosquito. You'll kill the other support files in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
It occurs when you use the scaffold generator.
It automatically creates a factory in test/factories/
So generally just deleting this file solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turned out there was a default `users.rb` created inside the `test/factories` which was created by the `rails g` command. This file was causing the conflict. The error went away when I deleted the file.

Comment: The `rails generate model <my-model>` caused this issue for me too because I was using rspec. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to run

> rake db:test:prepare

Answer (score 0):

I just found I was getting this answer when accidentally calling `cucumber features`. When I just called `cucumber`, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the same name factory at factories.rb, and I just found that someone else define the same factory below the directory of factories. So actually I can just use it without define another one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the refinerycms-testing gem with rspec-rails and factory_girl_rails

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you added factories through the model generator.   My generator made a model and I added one to my main factory.rb file.   Deleting the automatically generated ones worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

First my co-worker has setup the project with `factory_girl` gem with

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/factories/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

in `rails_helper`.

After some days, I replaced the gem with `factory_girl_rails`. Since this new gem also does that internally so factories were registered twice. This was causing the error.

Removed that line from `rails_helper` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this because I was trying to create two factories. My feature spec included the line:

```
let!(:user) { create(:user) }
```

And then I used a sign_up(user) helper method:

```
def sign_up(user)
  visit '/users/sign_up'
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
  fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: user.password_confirmation
  click_button 'Sign up'
end
```

Back to my feature spec, I called:

```
context 'logging out' do
  before do
    sign_up(user)
  end

...
```

thus effectively trying to sign up a User that was already being created by the factory.

I altered the  `sign_up(user)` to `sign_in(user)`, and the helper to:

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
  click_button 'Log in'
end
```

now the `user` argument creates the User in the db due to the `let!` block and the `sign_up(user)` logs them in.

Hope this helps someone!

oh! and I also had to comment out:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/factories/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

as a lot of the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The strangest thing, I got this error with the following syntax error in the code:

```
before_validation :generate_reference, :on: :create
```

`:on:` was causing this error. How or why will remain a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing `spec/factories/xxx.rb` from command line:

```
rspec spec/factories/xxx.rb spec/model/xxx.rb # before
rspec spec/model/xxx.rb # after
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, this issue was coming because was using both gems

```
gem 'factory_bot_rails'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

to solve I removed `gem 'factory_bot_rails'` from gem file.
and also added `require 'factory_girl'` to `spec/factories/track.rb` file.

```
if Rails.env.test?
    require 'factory_girl'
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :track do
            id 1
            name "nurburgring"
            surface_type "snow"
            time_zone "CET"
       end
    end
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just adding `required: false` to `gem 'factory_bot_rails'` like so:

```
gem 'factory_bot_rails', require: false
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that you don't have multiple factories with same name this is one of reasons which causes error

**Attempting to define multiple factories with the same name will raise an error.**