# FactoryGirl — Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463223/factorygirl-not-registered-only-one-factory-runs-into-this) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300231/factory-already-registered-user-factorygirlduplicatedefinitionerror). I'm loading `factory_girl_rails` fine.

I figured it must be a syntax error, but after an hour of head scratching, really haven't been able to fix it. Can someone please help? :)

Here is my factory:

```
require 'Faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Lorem.characters 12 }
  end

  trait :with_teams do
    ignore do
      number_of_teams 5
    end

    after :create do |user, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list :team, evaluator.number_of_teams, :user => user
    end
  end

end
```

And here is the relevant spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  # This works fine
  it "can create a team" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    team = user.teams.create

    team.class.should == Team
  end

  # The marked line throws argument error
  it "can have many teams" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user, :with_teams, :number_of_teams => 10 # <---
    user.teams.length.should == 10
  end
end
```

And this is the error I'm getting from running the spec:

```
    Failures:

      1) User can have many teams
         Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create :user, :with_teams, :number_of_teams => 10
         ArgumentError:
           Factory not registered: User
         # ./spec/factories/users.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traits should be inside factories. In your code, `:user` factory and `:with_teams` trait are not related.

```
require 'Faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Lorem.characters 12 }

    trait :with_teams do
      ignore do
        number_of_teams 5
      end

      after :create do |user, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list :team, evaluator.number_of_teams, :user => user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmmm I think that might be it, although I'm not getting the `trait not found` error (which i did get at some point). I'll try it out soon thank :)

Comment: Well, you are trying to use `:user` at that particular line. Tell us about the result then.

Comment: yeah, still installing rvm on my laptop hahaha

Comment: nope, I put the trait inside `:user` factory and still get factory not found, although it's really weird. The *results keeps alternating* from 0 examples (all examples filtered out) to 1 example 1 success (erronous example ignored) and finally 2 example 1 success 1 failure (with :user factory not found). I'm thinking could it be a caching problem of some sort?

Comment: FactoryGirl.create :male_user, :traits => [:with_teams]

Comment: Thanks Hélio, that last comment helped me. Also realized that RubyTest in Sublime Text was testing within the cursor's placement scope, and that was why I was getting varying results hahaha silly me...

Comment: No problem. Feel free to improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.factories.clear
```

This may fixed your problem.

Comment: Tried that before, I get a load of errors including `Factory already registered:`

Comment: Right, put this in spec_helper

Comment: I also had to do a `FactoryGirl.reload`

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see is that you don't have a factory called `teams`.

```
require 'Faker'
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
  team
   #.... your code here
  end

  factory :team do
   #... more code here as necessary 
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi vlasits, thanks for that but I had a factory called teams, forgot to mention that sorry!

Answer (score 1):

As a [wintondeshong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338305/wintondeshong) says in comments here - you probably should to reload your factories, but previously you can check if they present:

```
FactoryGirl.factories.count
FactoryGirl.factories
```

then

```
FactoryGirl.reload
```